Einstein Email Recommendations not populating
I am implementing Einstein email recommendations and have been following along with the documentation. I have a catalog uploaded and I have the tracking code on my website. Now the tracking code seems to work intermittently at best. I am receiving views but no profiles or consistent tracked items ( it will show tracked items but not at the quantity I would expect). I believe it is an issue with how the the code was placed on the website but i'm not sure what is happening.
I placed the base collect code in my head tag:
<script>
    var _etmc = [];
    _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "534010071"]);
    _etmc.push(['trackPageView']);
    _etmc.debug = true;  
    </script>

and for track item i have this code placed:
var _etmc = [];
_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "534010071"]);
_etmc.push(["trackPageView", { "item" : productSKU.trim() }]); 

And for setUserinfo I have this code in place:
console.log(loggedUserEmail)
        var _etmc = [];
        _etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": loggedUserEmail }]);
        _etmc.push(['trackPageView']);

In the network tab I only see the collect.js tag. Before I did see a trackingpageview request but It didn't include any information except the title of the webpage.
